# Bootstrap Gallery with Lightbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, lightbox

I'm using the ekko lightbox along with bootstrap modal to create a gallery. However I cant seem to get the image navigation controls to appear/work like they do on this example: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery

As you can see when you hover over an image you get navigation control arrows. I've tried adding the data attribute data-gallery="multiimages" to my images but this hasnt helped.

You can see my development code here: http://agtdesigns.co.uk/bootstrap-gallery/

Any help appreciated,

tia

Comment: Did you include the Glyphicons Fonts folder and the path is correct? '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'

Comment: I uploaded the fonts folder too, but not sure where I am supposed to link to it?

Comment: Should be in the same folder as the css folder, 3 folders should be there css,js,fonts

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem,
see https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox/issues/33 for the answer.

In summary, you need to add a wrapping div, eg

```
<div class="gallery">
```

Then as JS code

```
$(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return $(this).ekkoLightbox({
            always_show_close: true,
            gallery_parent_selector: '.gallery',
    });
});
```